# How to insert new data from a table to another table?

Tags: php, mysql

I have 2 tables with names `search` and `search2`. When user search something on my website it's insert to first table and mySQL allocate auto increment ID to that. I want to ID from `search` table insert to `search2` table automatically. These are my tables structure:

```
TABLE search(
    id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    search_keyword VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL
)
TABLE search2(
    id INT FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES search (id)
)
```

and this is my query:

```
INSERT INTO search2 (id) SELECT id FROM search WHERE condition
```

I don't know what to write in condition that each time new record added to `search` table then it's ID insert to `search2` table.

NOTE: my website wrote by PHP.

Comment: First you have to add a record to search and after that you have to add a record into sreach2 with the last_insert_id from search.

Comment: create trigger after insert

Comment: As stated by @Jens you can look at [mysqli.insert-id](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.insert-id.php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create trigger after insert

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE TRIGGER new_load_id 
AFTER INSERT ON search
FOR EACH ROW 
INSERT INTO search2 (id) VALUES (NEW.id);

END$$
DELIMITER ;
```